# How to remove an event created with vnode.context.$on in a Vue directive?

Tags: vue.js

On directive bind I created a listener to the event 'validate' to run the function updateMessage:

```js
vnode.context.$on('validate', () => {
   updateMessage(el, vm);
});
```

How Can i remove or override it when i unbind the directive?

```js
directives: {
    validate: {
      bind(el, _, vnode) {
        const vm = vnode.context;
        el.addEventListener('input', e => {
                updateMessage(e.target, vm);
        });
        vnode.context.$on('validate', () => {
                updateMessage(el, vm);
        });
          console.log('bind', el)
      },
     unbind(el, _, vnode) {
        el.removeEventListener('input', e => {
                updateMessage(e.target, vm);
        });
         console.log('unbind',el)
     },
    }
  },
```

Comment: You could try [`vnode.context.$off('validate')`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off) which would remove all event listeners for that event

Comment: Thanks, that is a great idea and it works but it remove the event validate for all the elements. i need to remove it only for the elements that is unbinded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove this specific event handler, you'll need to store a reference to the handler function. You'll need to do the same for your *input* event handler too.

For example (assuming `updateMessage` is defined *somewhere*), store the event handlers on the element instances so you can reference them later

```js
validate: {
  bind(el, _, vnode) {
    const vm = vnode.context
    el.inputEventHandler = e => updateMessage(e.target, vm)
    el.validateEventHandler = () => updateMessage(el, vm)
    
    el.addEventListener('input', el.inputEventHandler)
    vm.$on('validate', el.validateEventHandler)
  },
  unbind(el, _, vnode) {
    el.removeEventListener('input', el.inputEventHandler)
    vnode.context.$off('validate', el.validateEventHandler)
  }
}
```

Thanks to [Decade Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734040/decade-moon) for the idea about storing the functions on the element.

Comment: This sounds great! I am trying this approach but i am stuck on the fact that i have multiple elements. should validateEventHandler be an array in the case i have different elements?

Comment: If you have multiple elements, then you should store the event handler on the element instance. Or you can use a global `WeakMap` to store the element-handler associations.

Comment: Phil, Decade Moon thank you for the answer. It has been really helpful and instructive :)